# initialization cycle of sub component and its parent component

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components

The lifecycle of Lightning Component is weird for me. A sub component needs to be initialized with data of  its parent component's attribute. However sometimes it works fine, sometimes does not. Are there docs for details?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Are you just looking for the Lightning docs?

Comment: @KrisGray thanks, Kris. Not just looking for Lightning docs. I have read 'developer guide'. Sometimes a sub component is needed to enhance its parent with sub's client-side controller since the limitations of built-in Expression. But I find that the initialization cycle is a little wired, not very clearly. In other words, the outline of initialization is wanted.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Thanks, Kris. When the code is organised, I will post it later on.

Comment: @KrisGray Is there a package for Salesforce1 which can be used in Xcode to run with iPhone Simulator?That developer can work within 'simulated' Salesforce1 native app, not browser web app. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Salesforce1 is a hybrid app. We don't provide the container and most of the features inside are via the browser anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this doc link help? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.196.0.lightning.meta/lightning/components_lifecycle.htm

Note that this is a link to the preview version of our Summer '15 release. We updated the topic for this release.

Any feedback is welcome if we're not answering your question.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Keep the questions coming!